# Segmentation fault: 11 for my dynamic linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

**data.h**

```
struct Sub {
    int n;
    struct Sub *next;
}

struct Super {
    struct Sub *Sub
    void (*addSub)(struct Super *self, struct Sub *subRef);
}
```

**data.c**

```
static void addSub(struct Super *self, struct Sub *subRef) {
    struct Sub *head = self->Sub;

    while(head != NULL) { // throwing segmentation fault somewhere here
        head = head->next;
    }

    // assign subRef once we reach to the end.
}

struct Super *newSuper() {
    struct Super *super = malloc(sizeof(struct Super));
    super->addSub = addSub;
    return super;
}
```

**data_test.c**

```
int main() {
    struct Super *super = newSuper();
    super->addSub(super, malloc(sizeof(struct Sub)));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm relatively new to C, implemented linked list long time back but can't seem to get my head around the null problem, that's how it used to be. How can I detect the end of the list and add the new value to the end?

Comment: What does "11" have to do with anything in this question?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: learn to run things in your debugger. that will at least tell you which line it failed on.

Comment: what is SubCommands, dont see it defined anywhere

Comment: Where is `macroCommand` declared/defined?

Comment: I think `newSuper` isn't initializing all to NULL/zero, so at some point `next` points to invalid memory. but your code seems not to compile (missing semicolon after `struct Sub *Sub`)

Comment: @goodvibration parsing error `(Segmentation fault: 11) for my dynamic linked list`

Comment: and learn to step through with your debugger too

Comment: sorry guys, i fixed some of the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to initialize you new object

```
struct Super *newSuper() {
    struct Super *super = malloc(sizeof(struct Super));
    super->addSub = addSub;
    super->Sub = NULL;
    return super;
}
```

malloc'ed memory is not cleared to any value; it contains junk.

you should also have  a newSub function to create instance of your Sub objects instead of the caller using raw malloc

Comment: initializing super->Sub = NULL would have still crashed in addSub function. I modified addSub to prevent crash.

Comment: thats why you were crashing, you probably ended up crashing somewhere else after adding the assingment i suggest

Comment: `super->Sub = NULL;` was also the probable cause. see my comment on the other answer too for  a complete solution.

Comment: and I'm wondering, please enlighten me, if i `malloc` some structure, then all  member variables have to be initialized to `NULL`? I was assuming they are `NULL` by default, and if that the case checking `if(sub == NULL)` will crash?

Comment: second question, is it possible to embed the `Sub` struct inside `Super` while still able to assign `NULL` to `Sub` during the alloc phase?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please also look into another question, there's a lot of discussion but you can just ignore all and simply download and review the project for a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471963/anonymous-functions-return-dynamically-allocated-values

Answer (score 0):

Your `addSub` function is not doing the real thing, means it's not adding anything. you are traversing to the `null` node of the list and loosing the parent node. Better check for `head->next != null` and then add `sub` to the end as shown below. (I assume that you want to add `subRef` to the end of the list)

```
static void addSub(struct Super *self, struct Sub *subRef) {
    struct Sub *head = self->Sub;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        self->Sub = sub;
        return;
    }

   while(head->next != NULL) { // throwing segmentation fault somewhere here
       head = head->next;


   head->next = subRef;
   subRef->next = NULL; //This step is only required if subRef->next 
                        //was not set to null before the call
  }
```

Comment: nope - this is still going to fail. self->Sub has not been initialized anywhere

Comment: i figured out, the problem is with `head->next = subRef;`, it should be `head = subRef`

Comment: @Developer: what problem ? head = subRef is not correct, my code for addSub and pm100 code for newSuper together should work fine for you.

Comment: @Developer: if your problem is solved then please mark my response `answered`. appreciate it. Thanks !

Comment: because after while loop ends, the head will point to `NULL`, and then accessing `head->next` (aka `NULL->next`) is going to crash obviously. Sorry, your answer didn't point to the solution in it's entirety. both answers helped though. however, pm100 response enlightened on the NULL initialization at allocation time.

Comment: @Developer: when while loop ends (aka: head->next != NULL) head will point to the last element in the list and not NULL. it will never become NULL->next